# PHP: How to loop and retrieve values of multiple inputs of form with the different name attribute?

Tags: php

I would like to loop and retrieve values of multiple inputs of this form below for the best way, so how can i do, I have tried many times but unfortunately I did not succeed

here are the view code and controller code

```
<form action="../controller/Store/ExpensesUSD.php" method="POST">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <?php foreach($ExpensesUpdate AS $Expenses_Update): ?>

      <select name="ProductServiceID[]">
        <?php foreach ($expenses_registered AS $Expenses_Registered): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $Expenses_Registered->ExpenseID; ?>">
            <?php echo $Expenses_Registered->ProductServiceName; ?>
           </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>

      <input type="number" name="TotalAmountUSD[]" id="TotalAmountUSD" placeholder="please enter an expense..." value="<?php echo $Expenses_Update->DeservedAmountUSD; ?>">

      <input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $debts_separate->ID; ?>" readonly>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div> <!-- end input-wrapper -->

  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" 
 id="registerbtn">Enter</button>

</form>
```

---

```
$ID                     = (int)$_POST['ID'];
$ProductServiceID       = $_POST['ProductServiceID'];
$TotalAmountUSD         = $_POST['TotalAmountUSD'];
$PossibilityOFUpdating  = 'No';
$UpdatingDeletingStatus = 'Updated';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\_POST Array from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form)  It looks like the issue isn't that you aren't getting the values, it's that you're treating the value as an integer when what's being posted is an *array* of integers.  `$_POST['ID']` returns an array.

Comment: Properly indent your code and the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: no, my code have three different name attributes name="ProductServiceID[]" -  name="TotalAmountUSD[]" -                        name="ID[]"

Comment: @Mohammed: What do you mean by "three different name attributes"?  Any given form element can have only one `name`.  Your multiple form values are simply being posted as arrays, aren't they?  What's the specific problem?

Comment: My question is how to fetch by an array

Comment: @Mohammed: The linked duplicate demonstrates how to read a posted array.

Comment: Voted for reopening. While the topic is the same, the user makes a different mistake than the user of the related question.

Comment: @Mohammed @David The problem is not reading an array, the issue is that `ID` should not be part of the array. There is only one `ID` and not one `ID` per expense update. It should be outside of the loop.

Comment: thanks I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922916/php-post-loop-multiple-fields